# Ошибка в скрипте при переходе на якоря в HTML документе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот есть рабочий скрипт для якорей на странице:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("a[href^='#']").click(function () {
            var _href = $(this).attr("href");
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(_href).offset().top + "px"});
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Однако, в подвале фиксированная кнопка "вверх" http://joxi.ru/Dr8nabLCw73l26 при нажатии на нее происходит скрол вверх, к началу страницы, а скрипт при нажатии ругается ошибкой:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement. (common.js:5)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)

Я даже пробовал сделать скрипт "наоборот":

```
    $(function () {
        $("a[href^='#to-top']").click(function () {
            var _href = $(this).attr("href");
            $("html, body").animate({scrollBottom: $(_href).offset().bottom + "px"});
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Без результата...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно вашему коду, у вас на странице должен быть элемент с `id`, начинающимся на `to-top` (или что там у вас прописано в атрибуте `href`?)

```html
<div id="to-top">...</div
```

В противном случае jQuery не может найти нужный элемент по селектору `$(_href)` другими словами по `$("#to-top")`

Comment: вы знаете, действительно какая-то ошибка с id была, не понятно, выяснял, но стоило заново скопировать правильное название, как стало работать.

Спасибо работает!